# Proving Green's theorem for more general regions

Tags: multivariable-calculus, line-integrals, greens-theorem

Green's theorem says the following:

Let $R$ be a region in $\mathbb{R}^2$ whose boundary is a simple closed curve $C$ which is piecewise smooth. Let $\mathbf{f}(x,y)=P(x,y)\mathbf{i}+Q(x,y)\mathbf{j}$ be a smooth vector field defined on both $R$ and $C$. Then

$$
\oint_C P\text{d}x + Q\text{d}y={\int\int}_R\left(\dfrac{\partial Q}{\partial x}-\dfrac{\partial P}{\partial y}\right)\text{d}x\text{d}y.\tag{*}
$$

However, the proof that I have seen in many books only shows that this is true for a *simple* region $R$. That is, regions $R$ such that any line parallel to the $x$-axis or $y$-axis only intersects $R$ in a single line segment. However, Green's theorem works for all regions $R$ satisfying its hypotheses - not just simple ones.

[Green's theorem for union of simple regions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vPya4.jpg)

The image above shows a more general region which is the union of simple regions $D_1$, $D_2$, and $D_3$. I understand how Green's theorem can be shown to work for this specific case. We can apply (*) to each of the simple regions $D_i$. Summing the right hand sides up will give us the required double integral over the whole region $D=D_1+D_2+D_3$. Summing the left hand sides up will also give us the required line integral over $C=C_1+C_2+C_3$ because the line integral over $D_1$ has a $-E_1-E_2$ component, while the line integrals over $D_2$ and $D_3$, respectively, have an $E_1$ and an $E_2$ component - so everything cancels nicely.

However, I do not see how to generalize this approach to all regions of this kind. I would like a rigorous proof that Green's theorem works for regions that are the union of simple regions.

Comment: Break your region down into simple regions that border one another.  Get the line integrals and area integrals of each region.  Each line/area pair will satisfy the Green's thm eqn.  Add up all the line integrals on the one hand, and all the area integrals on the other.  The two sums will be equal.  Now: The line integrals of any two border regions will cancel along their common border.  All that will be left will be the outside curve integral and the area integrals.  So Green's thm will be satisfied.

Comment: I used to feel frustrated that it was difficult to find a nice, rigorous treatment of Green's theorem and Stokes's theorem that was not limited to special cases. Eventually I realized that many authors prefer to just develop the generalized Stokes's theorem, which has Green's theorem and the classical Stokes's theorem as special cases, because that approach is more general, more elegant, and not too much harder (debatable), and because math authors tend to find it more interesting to write about. So you might want to learn about Stokes's theorem on a manifold with boundary (or w/ corners).

Comment: @littleO The plan is to get there eventually but I'm working on a project where it would be nice to have a rigorous proof of Green's theorem without too much machinery (since I have very limited space).